# Is there a formula for Re($z^n$)?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z$ is a complex number, it is well known that $2 Re(z) = z + \bar{z}$. Is it there a compact / clean expression for $Re(z^n)$ in the sense that it may depend on z, |z|,  $\bar{z}$, Re(z) or Im (z), but not x, y, $\theta$? I have been trying various options but nothing came to mind, other than  $|z|^n \cos(n\theta)$, which depends on $\theta$.

Comment: it is $(z^n+\bar z^n)/2$ but not sure that is what you want; in terms of $x,y$ the formulas are not that nice

Comment: That comes almost directly from the one I mentioned, I am looking for an alternative that may depend on z, |z|,  $\bar{z}$, Re(z) or Im (z), but not x, y, $\theta$

Comment: yup, that is the one I mentioned

Comment: I'm not a sure if this is quite what you're looking for, but De Moivre's theorem allows you to express $|z|^{n}\cos(n\theta)$ in terms of $\text{Re}(z)=|z| \cos\theta$ and $\text{Im}(z)=|z| \sin\theta$.

Comment: Not really, see my comments above. Maybe I am looking for something that doesn't exist, other than what @Conrad mentioned

Comment: Conrad's suggestion isn't quite the same as just replacing $z$ with $z^n$ in the formula $\mathrm{Re}(z) = (z + \overline{z})/2$ since it uses $\overline{z^n} = \overline{z}^n$.

Comment: $\Re z^n$ is a homogenous (harmonic) polynomial of degree $n$ in either $\Re z, \Im z$ coordinate system or in the $z, \bar z$ coordinate system (both of course on $\mathbb R^2$) so I am not sure what you look for; imho nothing simpler than $P(u,v)=(u^n+v^n)/2$ for $u=z, v=\bar z$ exists but an example for $n=2$ may illuminate the issue

Comment: @Mike F. Noted. That is why I said "almost directly", and not simply "directly"